# Upgrading to Laravel 5 reflection error

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to upgrade from laravel 4 to 5 and have been following the official laravel upgrade guide. I have encountered the following error :

**ReflectionException in Container.php line 776:
Class HomeController does not exist**

```
in Container.php line 776
at ReflectionClass->__construct('HomeController') in Container.php line 776
at Container->build('HomeController', array()) in Container.php line 656
at Container->make('HomeController', array()) in Application.php line 644
at Application->make('HomeController') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 83
at ControllerDispatcher->makeController('HomeController') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 54
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'HomeController', 'users') in Route.php line 204
at Route->runWithCustomDispatcher(object(Request)) in Route.php line 134
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 701
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 703
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 670
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 628
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 214
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 43
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 17
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 55
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 61
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 36
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 40
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 115
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 84
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

to my understanding this was because I was relying on the now depricated html service providers I have included these in my project as per :

```
composer


{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.*",
        "chumper/datatable": "dev-develop",
        "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php",
            "app/Http/Controllers" ,
             "app/Models"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\"",
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

and app

```
'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider',
         'Chumper\Datatable\DatatableServiceProvider',
         'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',

        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        'App\Providers\AppServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\BusServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\ConfigServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\EventServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider',

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Class Aliases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
    | is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
    | the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
    |
    */

    'aliases' => [

        'App'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\App',
        'Artisan'   => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan',
        'Auth'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth',
        'Blade'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade',
        'Bus'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus',
        'Cache'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache',
        'Config'    => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config',
        'Cookie'    => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie',
        'Crypt'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt',
        'DB'        => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB',
        'Eloquent'  => 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model',
        'Event'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event',
        'File'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\File',
        'Hash'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash',
        'Input'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input',
        'Inspiring' => 'Illuminate\Foundation\Inspiring',
        'Lang'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang',
        'Log'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log',
        'Mail'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail',
        'Password'  => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password',
        'Queue'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue',
        'Redirect'  => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect',
        'Redis'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis',
        'Request'   => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request',
        'Response'  => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response',
        'Route'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route',
        'Schema'    => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema',
        'Session'   => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session',
        'Storage'   => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage',
        'URL'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL',
        'Validator' => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator',
        'View'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\View',
        'Datatable' => 'Chumper\Datatable\Facades\DatatableFacade',
        'Form' => 'Collective\Html\FormFacade',
        'Html' => 'Collective\Html\HtmlFacade',

    ],

];
```

I still unfortunately am still encountering the error any help is as always greatly appreciated thanks

Comment: Where have you stored the controllers in the app directory?

Comment: @Arjan96s   the controllers are stored in : C:\xampp\htdocs\awsconfig\app\Http\Controllers thanks

Comment: @Arjan96s which is where I presume they should go

Comment: @RichardHewitt Are you add namespace `App\Http\Controllers` in controller file. Laravel 5 used namespace for Controller.

Comment: @NyanLynnHtut Thanks the official documentation says that namespacing is optional I modified the route service handler to set $namespace to null as per docs

Comment: @RichardHewitt But you need namespace for Controller. Because Laravel 5 does not have class map for controller folder like Laravel 4. Laravel 5 used PSR 4 Standard (check in composer.json). Compare L4 and L5 `composer.json` for different.

Comment: @NyanLynnHtut you are correct I have modified my files accordingly thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in the aliases section it should be HTML not Html correcting this will solve the problem in this instance.